# jQuery mobile + iScroll, cannot scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll4, iscroll

I'm trying to integrate [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) with [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). I am aware that there is already a [project](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) that does this, however, I'm avoiding it due to a [bug](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview/issues/55) with input-elements (page jumping like crazy when typing).

My current implementation looks like this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/AqHsW/** - *(JSFiddle example)* [[Alternative mirror](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16088211/soBug.html)]

As you probably noted, this works flawlessly, except for one major catch:
**one cannot scroll down.** This problem seems to be cross-os / browser.

However, if my I override the `onBeforeScrollStart` method:

```
var scroller = new iScroll('wrapper', { onBeforeScrollStart: null });
```

It works somewhat better. Now one can scroll, but the behaviour gets glitchy (along with slow responsiveness) instead, allowing the user to scroll how high he wants and so on.

*(Doing this only seems to alter things on iOS, however)*

I'm now looking for a solution to this problem, which preferably supports iOS 5 and 6, along with the use of `<input>` elements. This should be a pretty common problem, considering that iScroll and jQuery Mobile are the two dominating frameworks today.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I played a bit with your code, found a couple of things and a solution, check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUK88/2/).

- Since your loading *jQuery*, make use of `jQuery(document).ready()`.
- It seemed more appropriate to init *iScroll* on the `wrapper`'s direct child element rather than the `wrapper`.
- Instead of setting the wrapper height via CSS, I used javascript to be more precise and avoid overflows.
- FYI, `scroll` was already defined as a function. *(in your fiddle you used `scroll` as a variable)*
- Now it works like a charm!

---

```
$(function(){

    var footerHeight = $('[data-role="footer"]').outerHeight(true),
        headerHeight = $('[data-role="header"]').outerHeight(true),
        padding = 15*2; //ui-content padding

   $('#wrapper, #scroller').height( $(window).innerHeight() - headerHeight - footerHeight - padding );

   // To make inputs focusable,
   // you can rebind their touchend's event to trigger their focus

   $('input').on('touchend', function(){
       $(this).focus();
   });

   var iScroller = new iScroll('scroller');

});​
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and help, it's really, really appreciated! Your solution fixes the initial problem, however, only the first element will be scrolled. [ http://jsfiddle.net/NUK88/4/ ] (the other content is left in the background, un-scrolled).. Nor cannot `<input>` elements be selected. I've tried various `onBeforeScrollStart` overrides, but them all breaks your solution..

Comment: You don't happen to have any ideas on how to solve this? I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: Your welcome, I updated my answer to include the un-selectable inputs fix, however, I can't see the other problem you'r describing about the first element being scrolled only.

Comment: Thank you once again, that fix worked perfect aswell. http://jsfiddle.net/6jXfy/ Here, the `<h1>` isn't visible (it's under the header), but that's the scroll-able element, and the list is not scrollable. I'm testing on iOS 6 and Firefox 16.

Comment: @Zar That is because your `h1` is not in the right place, and currently being considered as one of iScroll's scrollable-items, he should be a direct child of `#content`. http://jsfiddle.net/VDrUT/3/

Comment: I'm actually trying to get all content (`data-role="content"`) to be scrollable, that means trying to get the (in this case) `<h1>` to scroll along with the rest of the content. In other words, all `#scroller` content.. Haha got messy, I hope you understood me.

Comment: Ah my bad didn't get that, the whole content scrollable updated here http://jsfiddle.net/VDrUT/4/

Comment: @Pierre Hello again, I've been playing around a bit with your solution and it's working as expected. One catch, though. It only works if run through `$(document).ready()`, and not $("#page-id").bind('pageinit', function() {  /* here */ }); `. This means that it only can be run on the first page, and not on several pages.. Any idea for a solution?

Comment: @Zar, not really. I think we have derived from the main question here. This should be another question with more info on the problem and more complete code :)

Comment: @Pierre You're absolutely right. Thanks so much for all your help, it's truly, truly appreciated! I owe you a big one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may see this demo: http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/event-passthrough/

```
myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { eventPassthrough: true, scrollX: true, scrollY: false, preventDefault: false });
```